# list indices must be integers, not list - Using a Dict in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having trouble with this part of a code chunk in a long program

```
print GInfo[i].DualVariables, "\n", GInfo[i].Components
for i in GInfo[i].Components:
  print i, tuple(i)
  if (tuple(i) not in GInfo[i].DualVariables):
    ------ Do Something ---------
```

Here GInfo is an object of a class GraphInfo

```
class GraphInfo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.G = nx.Graph()
    self.Components = []
    self.ActiveStatus = {}
    self.ContainsCommon = {}
    self.p = {}
    self.Edges = []
    self.DualVariables = {}
    self.Bound = {}
```

As one can see the DualVariables is a dict and Components is a list. The output for a sample instance for the code is as follows:

```
{(0,): 0.0, (1,): 31.5, (2,): 31.5, (8,): 31.5, (3,): 31.5, (4,): 31.5, (5,): 31.5,(6,): 31.5, (7,): 31.5} 
[[8, 7], [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
[8, 7] (8, 7)
```

followed by the error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
```

in the line where the if condition is present.

Any help with this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `i` in the loop to something different, for example:

```
print GInfo[i].DualVariables, "\n", GInfo[i].Components
for j in GInfo[i].Components:
  ...
```

Comment: @pondy Great! May I then please ask you to mark the answer as correct? :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends a bit what you want to do:

```
if tuple(i[0]) not in GInfo.DualVariables.keys():
    ...
```

or maybe

```
if GInfo.DualVariables[tuple(i[0])] != i[1]:
    ...
```

Do either of these fit what you're trying to do?

Comment: But piokuc makes a good point too.

Comment: ``something not in somedict.keys()`` is equivalent to ``something not in somedict``, except that the latter (as opposed to the former) doesn't create a list in python2 and is a lot faster in all python versions. (with ``.keys()``, you make lookup in a list instead of a dictionary, which is slow)